# Can I use variables in JSON-LD?

Tags: html, schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I'm trying to implement Schema.org in a FAQ page, but it seems repetitive to re-write all the questions and answers in the schema.

So I was wondering if I could call a variable or a class in my JSON-LD to retrieve the questions and answers from the body.

Something like the code below:

```html
<head>
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "FAQPage",
      "url": "https://www.example.com",
      "mainEntity": [{
        "@type": "Question",
        "name": {{question}},
        "acceptedAnswer": {
          "@type": "Answer",
          "text": {{answer}}
        }
      }]
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 class="question">This is question number one?</h3>
    <p id="answer"> This is the answer to Q1.</p>

    <h3 class="question">This is question number 2?</h3>
    <p class="answer">This is the answer to Q2.</p>
</body>
```

Comment: You could switch to using microdata which wraps around the html. Or write some JavaScript that replaces those variables. or dynamically generates the whole json-ld.

Answer (score 2):

No, JSON-LD doesn’t allow this.

If you don’t want to repeat your content, you can use Microdata or RDFa. With these syntaxes, you add attributes to your existing HTML elements ([details](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/328711/63183)).

With RDFa, it could look like:

```html
<body typeof="schema:FAQPage">

  <link property="schema:url" href="https://www.example.com/" />

  <article property="schema:mainEntity" typeof="schema:Question">

    <h3 property="schema:name">This is question number one?</h3>

    <div property="schema:acceptedAnswer" typeof="schema:Answer">
      <p property="schema:text">This is the answer to Q1.</p>
    </div>

  </article>

</body>
```

(by using RDFa’s `vocab` attribute e.g. on the `html` element, you could omit the `schema:` prefix; by using RDFa’s `prefix` attribute, you could define a different, e.g. shorter, prefix)